# kafka-topics.bat --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 is not returning list

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-topic

[kafka-topics.bat --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 is not returning anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKGRn.png)

kafka-topics.bat --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 is not showing anything

The above command meant to show me the topic list but it wasn't returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

It can only be two things

- The cluster at localhost:9092 does not have any topics
- There are ACL's preventing you from listing topics.

Have you tried creating a topic first? You can do this with

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic first_topic --create --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1
```

Comment: Yes, I create 2 topics but none of them are showing while listing.

Comment: How did you create the topics? was it also using the cli?

Comment: Yes, The issue is resolved I restarted everything and then ran the your code again. Thanks